# System x3550 M2 stuck on system initializing after firmware upgrades

Tags: ibm

I have been having this major issue for the last few hours now.
I have a system x 3550M2 server and I ran the UEFI and IMM firmware upgrades within Windows Server 2008 R2 x64.

All upgrades went fine and I was told to reboot. I performed the reboot cleanly using the OS restart option. Upon restarting it showed the system initializing screen and it stayed there for a good hour. After that hour I figured it froze and so I powered down and powered up again.

Now I can not boot back up to even see the IBM splash screen or the OS... I have tried switching the Jumpers to go to the backup UEFI and backup IMM and no luck. I have also reset the CMOS power and I have pressed the reset button 3 times on the light path and no luck. There are no lights light on the light path to indicate anything is broken. The only thing I see on the light path is the number 0.5.
Any ideas?  I am quite stumped with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

don't forget unplugging from power - this is not a joke. unplug the machine from the outlets for at least 30s.

Comment: +1 for that! After administering bunch of xSeries servers for years I can tell you that *many* mysterious problems disappear after unplugging the machine from the outlet for a minute or so and plugging it back in. "Mysterious problems" including "hard server freezes" and "degraded performance".

Comment: confirming PFO answer
after software reboot, have to power cycle the server
netcomp

Answer (score 0):

Pull the CMOS battery for 5 minutes, then replace the battery and try starting the system again.

If it still fails to boot, call IBM for hardware support (+1-800-IBM-SERV).

Answer (score 0):

Power off machine and press F1 while booting.  As you saw, it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

just open cover of your cpu and find the jumper j2 (Bios jumper) and change port 1,2 to 2,3 
restart the server if it still there 
plug out then plug in the main port 
then restart it will work 100 %